# Is this argument correct to show that I have an isometric isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a map $T:X \to Y$ between Hilbert spaces. I want to show that $T$ is isometrically isomorphic.

I have found:

1) For every $x \in X$, we have $Tx \in Y.$

2) For every $y \in Y$, there is an element $f(y) \in X$ with $Tf(y) = y$. The map $f$ is one-to-one and happens to be isometric.

I believe this shows that the map is isomorphism.

Now i need to show it's isometric. Am I right to argue like this:
Define $T^{-1}:Y \to X$ by $T^{-1}y = x$, where $x=f(y)$.
Then $|T^{-1}y| = |f(y)| = |y|$.
This is enough, right?

Comment: I dont see why T is injective. The afirmation in 2) guarantes only that T is sobrejective .  the function f is injective, if was then T is injective .  About the isometry  why $|f(y)| = |y|$ ?

Comment: Your assumption only shows $T$ is an isometric bijection on the image of $f$. In fact, if $f$ is not surjective, $T$ cannot be injective.

Comment: @Michael If I also proved that "$Tx_1 = Tx_2$ implies $x_1=x_2$" then is it enough?

Comment: @LeandroTavares $|f(y)|=|y|$ is just something I calculated for my specific case.

Comment: @OP Yes, then you'd be done. This is the same as saying $f$ is surjective.

Comment: then you finished the proof. T is injective because T is a isometry. your proof is correct ^^

Comment: Right. Because $T^{-1}$ is isometric, so is $T$. Then if $Tx-Ty=0$, by linearity of $T$, $T(x-y) = 0$ and taking norms and using isometricity of $T$, we get $|x-y| =0$ i.e. $x =y$. Thanks both for the help

Comment: @Michael I'm sorry but can you explain  why that is the same as saying $f$ is surjective? I don't understand.

Comment: @LeandroTavares Maybe you also know why $T$ being injective means $f$ is surjective?